# Binance - Mandatory parameter 'type' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed

Tags: node.js, enums, binance

I am trying to make a request to the [Binance API](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#user-universal-transfer) using the universal transfer call that requires 3 params: "asset", "value" and "type". However, when I make the call with the required params I get the following response:

```
{
  code: -1102,
  msg: "Mandatory parameter 'type' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed."
}
```

I can see that the parameter is being parsed in when I console.log but I still get the error:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  code: -1102,
  msg: "Mandatory parameter 'type' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed."
}
```

Here's the futuresTransferAsset() function I'm using the [API from here](https://github.com/jaggedsoft/node-binance-api)

```
futuresTransferAsset: async ( asset, amount, type ) => {
    let params = Object.assign( { asset, amount, type } );
    return promiseRequest( 'v1/futures/transfer', params, { base:sapi, type:'SIGNED', method:'POST' } );
},
```

Here is the request:

```
const result = await binance.futuresTransferAsset('USDT', 1.00, 'UMFUTURE_MAIN')
```

Am I not parsing in the type param correctly?

Comment: Could you please add futuresTransferAsset() function (*prevent expose sensitive data) and API doc. It might help us.

Comment: @marcode_ely Thanks for your comment, the API doc is in the link and I've added the function. The type parameter is required so I've parsed in the correct value but it says it's malformed.

Comment: @marcode_ely I thought the issue was solved but nah still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

hum! you're trying to build an Object in the line:

```
let params = Object.assign( { asset, amount, type } );
```

So you're passing three parameters to `futureTransferAsset()` function. This line says that:

```
futuresTransferAsset('USDT', 1.00, 'UMFUTURE_MAIN')
```

Check what happens when you tried to build an `Object` replacing the input params.

[image]

The "malformed" message could be related with a wrong definition of Object creating in `params` var definition.

This an example to define an `Object`:

[image]

`*assetKeyName`, `*amountKeyName` and `*typeKeyName` are a supposed key name as best practice of `Object` type definition.

In conclusion:

- There is a bad-definition of Object when tried to create `params` var.
- `params` var is passing in `promiseRequest` with a 'malformed' format or missing-format `Object`.
- May be you're missing the key names.
- This a question: Does the binance api allows receive Object type without key-pair format.

Please let know if I'm missing something.

Comment: How can I find ENUM value for `UMFUTURE_MAIN` ?

Comment: Hi alper, I have not a deep knowlage about BINANCE, but here you can find the api documentation. https://github.com/jaggedsoft/node-binance-api